# How do I determine my character's maximum load?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, d20-system, encumbrance

According to the d20 SRD regarding [carrying capacity](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/carryingCapacity.htm):

> A character can lift as much as his or her maximum load over his or her head.

What is the maximum load? Is it the same as the "heavy load" column shown in [Table: Carrying Capacity](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/carryingCapacity.htm#tableCarryingCapacity)?

Comment: Note: Learning how to play D&D from the SRD is a frustrating affair. It lacks all the "teaching" text, leaving only the rules and incomplete explanations of how to use them. You should really look into getting a copy of the PHB.

Comment: Not that @SevenSidedDie's opinion is his own and plenty of people (myself included) learned just fine of the SRD.

Comment: @KRyan But given these questions…

Comment: I have a copy of the PHB but was stuck in a wormhole at the time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, that is precisely it.

The Heavy Load column on the Carrying Capacity table indicates how much your character can carry and still move about for long periods of time, even if his reaction time is slowed down and he cannot run. The maximum Heavy Load is his maximum load.

In the Player's Handbook this is made clear in the first paragraph on page 162, where it states

> Tordek can't quite manage to carry her and her gear, because doing so would put him over his 200-pound maximum load.

which is the maximum heavy load listed for a character with Strength 15.

Comment: Heavy load is a range; to be explicit, "maximum load" is the maximum amount from the heavy load range.